# Using Raycasts.TextureCoord to draw onto 3d objects - not drawing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a game where you can use the mouse to draw on 3d objects, however when I use the mouse to draw it does not mark the texture. I am using Unity Personal Edition. I followed the [Raycast.TextureCoord](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html) documentation which has an example. I used the following C# code, almost exactly the same as the example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Paint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            return;

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
            return;

        Renderer rend = hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;

        if (rend == null || rend.sharedMaterial == null || rend.sharedMaterial.mainTexture == null || meshCollider == null)
            return;

        Texture2D tex = rend.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
        Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
        pixelUV.x *= tex.width;
        pixelUV.y *= tex.height;

        tex.SetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, Color.black);
        tex.Apply();
    }
}
```

I have this code in a script called paint. I created an empty project which has a texture with the read and write mode on with the convex off. The camera faces a cube and a plane. There is no moving functionality whatsoever. There is just a camera, attached is the paint c# script with the main camera attached. I have followed the instructions however it does not paint on to the cube when I click on to it. Why is this? How can I make it paint on to the cube.

Apologies if this is obvious as I am new to unity.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you select the object you want to paint on, take screenshot of the Inspector tab and post it?

Comment: Done. Do you think I need to enable a UV related feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Raycast.TextureCoord` works with `MeshCollider` not `BoxCollider`. When `Raycast.TextureCoord` is used on a `BoxCollider`, it will return 0,0 for Vector2. Remove the `BoxCollider` from the Cube GameObject then attach  `MeshCollider` to it and it should work.

**EDIT:**

> How come I cannot do it on the plane then? –

*You can do it on a plane* and it works on a plane but you can't see it because the drawing is too small. Zoom in on the plane from the Scene view or use the slider on the Game view to zoom in on the object, you will see the drawing. This is because the area you are drawing on it too small. You are also drawing black on a brown texture so that would be harder to see. Use red to veirydy this.

The example below added a `SIZE` variable to increase the area you are drawing to. The value of 5 should be fine and it uses red color instead of brown to draw it so that you can clearly see it. Note that this whole drawing thing should be done with shader or OpenGL but for the sake of fixing your issue, I will stick with `Raycasts.TextureCoord`.

```
public Camera cam;
public int SIZE = 5;

void Start()
{
    cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        return;

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (!Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
        return;


    Renderer rend = hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;

    if (rend == null || rend.sharedMaterial == null || rend.sharedMaterial.mainTexture == null || meshCollider == null)
        return;

    Texture2D tex = rend.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
    Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;

    pixelUV.x *= tex.width;
    pixelUV.y *= tex.height;

    //Expand where to draw on both direction
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        int x = (int)pixelUV.x;
        int y = (int)pixelUV.y;

        //Increment the X and Y
        x += i;
        y += i;

        //Apply
        tex.SetPixel(x, y, Color.red);

        //De-increment the X and Y
        x = (int)pixelUV.x;
        y = (int)pixelUV.y;

        x -= i;
        y -= i;

        //Apply
        tex.SetPixel(x, y, Color.red);
    }
    tex.Apply();
}
```

Comment: How come I cannot do it on the plane then?

Comment: See my Edit. That should answer your question